# object expression and captured state in F#

Tags: interface, f#

What makes the first implementation KO ?

```
type IToto  = 
    abstract Toto : unit -> unit

{ new IToto with  
      member this.Toto = 
             fun () -> () }

{ new IToto with  
        member this.Toto () = ()  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the compile representation, there is a difference between property of a function type, compiled as `FSharpFunc<unit, unit> Toto { get; }`, and a method taking unit and returning unit, compiled as `unit Toto()`.

The first object expression implements a different interface:

```
type IToto  = 
    abstract Toto : (unit -> unit) // Note: Parentheses around the function type!

{ new IToto with  
      member this.Toto = 
             fun () -> () }
```

Comment: this is getting subtle. I like.