# F# Lambda in Object Expression

Tags: lambda, f#

I can see people using lambdas in object expressions such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246660/object-expression-and-captured-state-in-f), but I can't quite figure out why the following idea doesn't work.

```
type fooType = {flar : string; grib: int}
let boundFoo = {flar = "hello"; grib = 1}
let flack = {boundFoo with grib = fun () -> if boundFoo.flar = "hello" then 5 else 4}
```

From what I can gather, it doesn't like `fun () ->`, but `fun _ ->` and `fun x ->` don't seem to lead anywhere different?

My research on this so far at my usual spots [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx), [F# for fun and profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/object-expressions/) and [google](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=f%23+lambda+in+object+expression) didn't lead me down any clear paths.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `grib` is an int. `fun () -> ...` is not an int, it's a function. Therefore `fun () -> ...` is not a valid value for the field `grib`.

If `grib` had the type `() -> int`, then your code would work (except that you'd have to change `grib = 1` on the previous line to `grib = fun () -> 1` of course), but that doesn't really seem a useful thing to do here. Really it does not seem like a function is really appropriate here. This will work fine:

```
let flack = {boundFoo with grib = if boundFoo.flar = "hello" then 5 else 4}
```